# Is it possible to find what is the random generated key if I know the plaintext and ciphertext?

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher, decryption

Is it possible to find what is the key with only plaintext and ciphertext?

For example,

My plaintext is: hi

My ciphertext is: 0x1db5

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Are you asking to find the keystream when a stream cipher is used to x-or the plaintext with the ciphertext? Then the answer is easy, x-or. If you are asking to find the key of your mystical stream cipher the answer is NO

Comment: Depends on the algorithm. If it is a correctly applied, secure algorithm with large enough key size, then no.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the stream cipher in question, then no.

If you do specify the stream cipher in question, and it meets some of the most modest security goals of a stream cipher, then no.

Comment: I am not sure, if the author had an established algorithm in mind or anything home-brewn.